# отправка в jsf бин данных из js при загрузке

Tags: javascript, java-ee, jsp, jsf

Есть ViewScoped бин. Он отображается на отдельной странице XHTML, имеет различные переменные для ввода и вывода информации и может редактироваться с этой страницы. После нажатия F5 бин сбрасывается к бину по умолчанию и все редактирование пропадает.

Я хочу с использованием js и sessionStorage "запоминать" состояние ViewScoped бина и возвращать его к нему после нажатия F5. (sessionScope не подойдет, хочу что бы один и тот же клиент мог в разных вкладках разные настройки применять).

Можно поместить в событие js onload некий скрипт, который будет восстанавливать состояние бина. Но к этому моменту бин уже загружен, а хотелось бы что бы от сразу загружался с нужными параметрами. Т.е. не так что бы сначала загружается бин с параметрами по умолчанию, а потом эти параметры меняются, а что бы сразу при загрузке получать со станицы нужные параметры.

Запихивать параметры в строку адреса (т.е. передавать в качестве Http атрибутов) не получиться, их очень много и не хочу так и т.д.

Возможно есть вариант передавать параметры в качестве http параметров. Т.е. так что бы можно было в бине из HttpServletRequest получить их т.е.

```
@Named
@ViewScoped
public class Bean implements Serializable
{
  @Inject
    private HttpServletRequest request;

    @PostConstruct
    public void firstInit() {
       Map<String, String> param  = request.getParameterMap();
       //код 
    }
}
```

Но я не понимаю как сделать так, что бы при инициализации бина эти самые параметры были переданы.
что писать в js? Или как еще это можно сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> что бы сразу при загрузке получать со станицы нужные параметры

> Запихивать параметры в строку адреса (т.е. передавать в качестве Http
> атрибутов) не получиться

Думаю, что соблюсти оба условия невозможно в случае обновления страницы по F5. F5 - это HTTP `GET`, в нём есть только URL и HTTP-заголовки. Если в них ничего не передать - получим полностью обновлённую страницу, без сохранения данных. Причём и на стороне сервера и на стороне клиента всё сбросится (если не применять технологии постоянных хранилищ в браузере).

Можно попробовать создать некий `Map` в компоненте `SessionScoped`, в котором ключом будет некий UID, а значением - состояние, которое надо восстановить. В `ViewScoped` бине создать метод с аннотацией `@PostConstruct`, который будет проверять наличие в URL некоего параметра (например, uid=). Если он есть, то находить в Map-е по этому ключу состояние в `SessionScoped` бине и восстанавливаться из него. Если параметра нет - значит это первое открытие страницы и ничего делать не надо. Плюс должно быть какое-то событие появления состояния, например, пользователь что-то ввёл и сделал сабмит формы. При обработке `action`-а кнопки можно создавать состояние на сервере, сохранять его в `SessionScoped` бине и по окончании обработки делать редирект, чтобы в URL-е появился параметр uid=. Могут возникнуть какие-то нюансы, до начала практической реализации их вряд ли получиться предусмотреть заранее.

Вообще, тут проблема скорее концептуальная и касается принципов `HTTP` в целом, а не специфики `JSF` в частности. Вероятно, стоит поискать решений, описанных без привязки к конкретной технологии, и адаптировать к `JSF`.